# How do I remove/hide the border of a pdf text field using Scribus?

Tags: pdf, scribus

I'm using Scribus 1.3.3.13 for windows and I'm trying to make a borderless pdf text field but I can't figure out how to do it.
Here are the steps I've taken:

- Created a blank document
- Added a pdf text field
- Opened the text field's properties
- Selected **Colors**

  - Clicked the **Line** button
  - Selected **None** from the list of colors

I thought this would make the border for the text field disappear but when I create a pdf and open it in Adobe Reader the border is still there. A friend of mine has the full Acrobat and was able to do this without any problems so I know its supported by the pdf format. Is this a bug in Scribus, a bug in Adobe Reader or am I missing a step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click the text field to bring up the context menu and select the following:

> PDF Options > Field Properties

The Field Properties dialog will appear.

[image: field properties dialog]

In the Appearance tab change the Color of Border to **None**.

Click **OK** and save/export as PDF.

Now when you view as PDF it will not show the border for the text field.

Comment: Why is Yoshi taking a rest? The princess is in another castle!